# Expressão regular para pegar input e header HTTP

Tags: regex

Como construir uma expressão regular que selecione isto aqui?

```
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=bf8748c0b1e113430d9757cf0ed06f4a; expires=Mon, 04-May-2015 20:54:08 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
```

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="676248f0994e62274dea72023fe699ff">
```

Pretendo fazer login com cURL no instagram.

Comment: Ainda não deu para entender o que você quer que a expressão regular selecione, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: eu so quero uma regex que pegue esses cookies e a input entende ?

Comment: Acho que entendi, editei novamente a pergunta. A primeira parte é um header http certo? Não faz parte do HTML.

Comment: exatamente isso mesmo :p

Comment: Será que utilizando a API do Instagram (http://instagram.com/developer) não resolve o problema? Se for logar para pegar as informações de usuários e tudo mais, vale a pena usar a API.

Comment: eu preciso so da expressao regular so isso

Answer (score 1):

*Não deu para entender muito bem o que a pergunta está pedindo mas, aqui vai uma tentativa.*

Tente utilizar a seguinte expressão:

```
/csrftoken=([\w]+)\;/
```

### [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ3aI4#pcre)

A segunda expressão:

```
/value=\"([\w]+)\"/
```

### [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tZ3aI0#pcre)